# Calling a Javascript Function explicitly in HAML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a if statement within in HAML view that check if there is a `flash[:notice]`, if so I want a javascript alert box to pop up with the notice message within it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why put this in your view? You can accomplish this with Javascript in your `application.js` *(or any other included JS file in your pipeline)*. You should really avoid putting Javascript directly into your view *(it's generally bad practice)*. The following HAML

```
#flash= flash[:notice]
```

would produce HTML like

```
<div id="flash">Your notice message here</div>
```

In your `application.js` you can do something like this

```
$(function() {
  if ($('#flash').get(0)) {    // check if the div exists
    alert($('#flash').text()); // throw an alert() with the div's text
  }
});
```

---

Maybe this serves your purpose fine, but there are better ways of doing this if you're not wanting the flash message text to appear in the HTML at all *(ie. assigning the flash message to a Javascript variable that is appended to the `<head>` in a `<script>` tag.)*

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky, but you can use `#{}` inside of javascript filters in HAML, like so:

```
- unless flash[:notice].empty?
  :javascript
    alert("#{flash[:notice]}");
```